# Is editing a good question with no answers to bump it to the homepage acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I've been querying unanswered/inactive questions recently, and I have come across some inactive (>3 months) questions which I feel are good questions but didn't get the viewership as of the date they were asked.

Is it acceptable to edit a question to bump it to the homepage to have it answered?

**Note**: The way I see it, getting a good question answered contributes to the site in a positive way, but I'm unsure of the standards here on Politics.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way to draw more attention to an important question is to [place a bounty](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

But making constructive edits to questions is always encouraged, even if the questions are older. Also, the [Community](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) bot is doing exactly the same thing to draw attention to questions without upvoted answers. So I would say that doing this is acceptable, as long as you have good judgment regarding what to bump or do some constructive edits to the question (correct spelling mistakes, give more descriptive tags, add links to sources, etc.).

Comment: I'm going along the right tracks then, thank-you for the clarification.